# How do I stop Python from running code right after I type it in?

Tags: python

I just started to code on Python, so I downloaded the "Python 3.10 (64-bit)". The problem is that it runs the code without my permission. For example, if I am trying to type in `print("example")` it just runs on it's own. This means I can't do an actual coding project, it just runs the 1 piece of code right after I hit the Enter button. I don't know if I'm just blind or it's obvious, but I can't figure it out. What do I do?

Comment: use a text editor or IDE to write code, then run the file you wrote the code in, don't use the shell

Comment: You are using the interactive interpreter; it's *supposed* to execute code one (logical) line at a time. Write your code in a file and execute the file when you are ready.

Comment: FWIW, this kind of thing is covered in the official Python Tutorial here: [Interactive Mode](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html#interactive-mode) and [Modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html). The official tutorial though is meant mostly for people who already know programming, so I don't know how helpful you'd find it.

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hitting enter after you type is "giving permission" to run the code that is typed (or copied)...

You can still write "scripts" this way - you define variables, functions, classes, etc, and they remain in scope of the interactive session.

If you want to "code a project," though, you should use an external IDE such as Visual Studio Code, PyCharm, Spyder, etc. The built-in [IDLE](https://docs.python.org/3/library/idle.html) is very basic, but still does allow for file execution.

Comment: Visual Studio Code is more of a text editor than an IDE, besides can use Notepad++, Notepad or even Word (jk on this one), the main point is that there's a file that stores the information

Comment: @Matiiss VSCode still can execute and debug Python code. Not sure what more it needs.

Comment: ok, so apparently VSC is classified as an IDE, but still, text editors can also be used to write code, to later execute, such that you can "code a project" in say Notepad++ or Sublime

Answer (score -1):

Where do you write your code?
If you are using the command line, you cannot do anything to change this; you have to use a file with the extension ".py", for example "first_file.py", and write the code inside that file. When you are done or when you want to test your code, you have to open the terminal in the file folder and type `python [filename].py` and after that, your code will be compiled and executed in the terminal. I recommend using a code-writing program like VS Code, Atom or something like that.

Comment: Atom project will be archived later this year, btw

Comment: Some of the phrasing here is not very clear, like "you cannot do anything to change this" and "you have to use a file". Like, what does "this" refer to? And what do you mean by "using a file" -- in the Python REPL? Keep in mind OP is new to programming, so you really need to spell things out and explain. Also, you don't *have* to use a terminal; for example, instead you could you could use an IDE to run it. (I didn't downvote though.)

Comment: be compiled? are you sure?

Comment: @MoRe Yes, technically, Python compiles to bytecode, which is then run on the Python Virtual Machine. But that's not super important for OP to know since they're new. Personally, I'd just say "run" instead of "compiled and executed".

Comment: @wjandrea I apologize for my English, I'm trying to improve it and maybe that's why some sentences seemed unclear. Thank you very much for the suggestions, I'll try to apply them and answer the questions more correctly.